# Get Current Sections ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to get ID of current section. Here is the code snippet what I tried:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    alert($(this).$("section").attr('id'));
}
```

But found no result. How can I get the **id** of a section while scrolling?

Comment: Try alert($("section").attr('id'));

Comment: Can you provide more clarification by providing more details about the code or codepen to work on ?

Comment: What you mean by current section? Provide more details to better understand and save time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are not detecting a current section in your code (by "current" I mean the section currently showing on the screen). To detect this section you should find current scroll position and compare it to section position.

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        $('section').each(function () {
            if($(this).position().top <= $(document).scrollTop() && ($(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight()) > $(document).scrollTop()) {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If [this plugin](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) works the way it should, then you could do this in the scroll event:

```
$('section').each(function() {
  if($(this).visible())
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this did not work here. Should I do something else to make it support? Although the answer of Natalia Tepluhina worked perfectly as I needed.

Comment: According to the [example code](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible/blob/master/examples/demo-basic.html#L29), that should have worked.